# PDP plots in Matlabs after running classification learner app

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, decision-tree

I have constructed ensemble bagged tree model in the classification learner app in Matlab.
The model is to predict binary variable (0 or 1). Most of the predictors are categorical.
(62 records, 5 folded cross validation, 40 variables./ 2 were excluded when fitted the model).
I have exported the model (named: trainedModel)

In order to interpret the model, I'm planning to use PDP (partial dependence plot).
I do not know what is the right way to do it, I need your valuable help on that. I am using the following code:

```
Mdl = trainedModel.ClassificationEnsemble;
pd = plotPartialDependence(Mdl,{'Age','exp_val'}); %age and exp_val are ordinal variables
```

[image]

- the data are clean and there are no missing values
- When ran the code error message says:

```
 Error using classreg.learning.classif.FullClassificationModel/plotPartialDependence (line 391)
Not enough input arguments.
```

Comment: Looking at the documentation for [`plotPartialDependence`](https://mathworks.com/help/stats/regressiontree.plotpartialdependence.html), I think you shouldn't have put the curly brackets in your function call. Try removing those, i.e. `plotPartialDependence(Mdl,'Age','exp_val');`

Comment: Have the following error:                 Error using classreg.learning.impl.parseArgsPPD>validateLabels (line 175)
At least one name in the third argument does not have a matching class label name.

Error in classreg.learning.impl.parseArgsPPD (line 34)
    [indLabels,labels] = validateLabels(model,labels);

Error in classreg.learning.impl.plotPartialDependence (line 70)
    classreg.learning.impl.parseArgsPPD(model,features,...

Comment: Error in classreg.learning.classif.FullClassificationModel/plotPartialDependence (line 423)
        ax = classreg.learning.impl.plotPartialDependence(this,features,...